# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(2).ConnectionString

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am just having a hard time figuring out what does the number 2 in

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(2).ConnectionString
```

define?

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's the connection string at the n-th index (in your case 2) in the connection string collection in your config.

Look in the ConnectionStrings section in your web.config/app.Config, and you will see which connection string you have defined with index = 2

I prefer referencing by name instead of integer index since it's a bit more clear which connection string you are targeting.

EX: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SomeConnectionStringName").ConnectionString`